# Aggregate duplicates based on two columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below

```
EMPID   EMPNAME MANAGERID
1       E1       M1
2       E2       M2
1       E3       M1
```

Need expected data like below.

```
EMPID   EMPNAME MANAGERID
1       E1,E3    M1
2       E2       M2
```

i.e eliminating the duplicates based on EMPID and MANAGERID and update the EMPNAME as shown.

Comment: I hope this URL would help you. http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#wm_concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a solution would be use WM_CONCAT

```
SELECT
          EMPID,
          WM_CONCAT(EMPNAME) ENMPNAME,
          MANAGERID
FROM 
          <table name>
GROUP BY
          EMPID,
          MANAGERID;
```

another solution (11gR2 +):

```
SELECT
          EMPID,
          LISTAGG(EMPNAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMPID, MANAGERID) EMPNAME,
          MANAGERID
FROM 
          <table name>
GROUP BY
          EMPID,
          MANAGERID;
```